Scipy Interpolation not good for fitting spot rates?
Trying to calculate a simple spot rate of a bond that has 2 cashflows left.
Maturity: 2025-05-15
Cashflows: $0.725$ coupon on 15-11-2024, then final on maturity

Dirty price is $99.703$
If I calculate YTM the usual way, it ties up:
$99.70 = \dfrac{0.725}{1.028061^{0.129}} + \dfrac{100.725}{1.028061^{0.625}}$
And, when I calculate the spot price of the last cashflow, I get $0.0283406$. This, as per below, ties up with the price:
$99.70 = \dfrac{0.725}{1.028061^{0.129}} + \dfrac{100.725}{1.028061^{0.625}}$
But how can this value ($0.028$) be so different from my spot curve, which is coming from the univariate spline from the 4 points below?
0    Ttm      Spot
1  0.129  0.032197
2  0.173  0.031714
4  0.342  0.030348
5  0.419  0.030995

Interpolation with in scipy.interpolate univariate interpolation


You're not interpolating, you're extrapolating. That is, you're creating the spline with data from $t=0.129$ to $0.419$ and then you're asking it for values outside that range. It doesn't really have that information. Splines are especially bad for that, because you'll extrapolate with a cubic and it will become very large quickly. Plot your rates until $t=2$ or $3$ to see what I mean.
If you want to have reasonable results for your home, you need more input data to cover that range.

Does that mean that a lower degree polynomial (i.e. quadratic) works better for extrapolation? Do you have any references you can provide? Thank you!

It doesn't work better; it might hide better the fact that you don't have information for that range of times.

In general, using splines to interpolate or extrapolate yield curves is tricky and easily leads to "hallucinations". People do use splines, but they require tweaking / constraining to make economic sense.
When trying to extrapolate, you might be better of with one of the following:
If the yield curve of some related risky bonds is actually a spread over a riskless/swap curve, and you have more data for the swap curve, then assume that the spread stays constant beyond your last observation. See Interpolating a yield from two yields (giving more weight to one of the two) for more detailed discussion.
If this isn't a spread over an underlying swap curve, then you could get the forward rate from the end of the yield curve that is observable, and extrapolate assuming the forward rate to be constant at longer tenors.
We should also mention Nelson Siegel, although it's not helpful here.

Thank you all!
I have found this paper: https://cosspp.fsu.edu/econpapers/wpaper/wp2011_08_03.pdf which is extremely interesting and I think I will follow. Instead of extrapolating spots, it builds the forward curve with constraints and then calculates spots. But the most interesting part is at the end, which I will paste below:

"The linear bootstrap with linear interpolation (LBLI) method is simply a
piecewise linear interpolation of the spot curve using a bootstrap method to
compute the spot rates at each node. This is straightforward for zero coupon
bonds when the the spot rates at those maturities are directly observed. For
bonds, we add one bond at a time and adjust the estimated spot rate up
or down until that bond is correctly priced. Note that the linear segments
determined in prior steps are not adjusted during this process. The resulting
spot curve will be continuous but not differentiable at the

..ode points.
Note first that the LBLI method produces zero pricing errors
for both the zero coupon bills and the coupon bearing bonds. This is precisely
what the LBLI algorithm is designed to do. The spot yields at each node
are chosen to exactly price the security maturing at that node. Since there is
no feedback from one node to previous nodes during the computations, zero
pricing errors is an easy criteria to satisfy. The problem with this method is
that, because the spot curve is piecewise linear, it produces discontinuities in
the spot and forward curves at the nodes."

If you work in an environment where models need to be reviewed / challenged by an independent model validation team, then simplicity - e.g. "this issuer has a 5-year bond trading with Z-spread n bps, therefore I assume that a new 10-year bond will have similar Z-spread", or "for this currency, 7Y and 10Y swap rates are observable, therefore I extrapolate the 15Y swap rate assuming constant forward rate" needs less explaining than something more sophisticated.
